# Freezing for about 2 minutes after desktop lock

Tags: nvidia, gnome, freeze, gnome-session-fallback

I run Ubuntu 22.04.3 and have a brand new PC with an Nvidia 4070. I will say that the nouveau driver works fine and on a windows 10 boot it works 100% fine. I've even stress tested the gpu and it's fine.

The issue I'm having is when I unlock my system the menu bar at the top of the screen and other parts of the system are locked up. it takes about 2 minutes and then it works fine. I'm using gnome-session-flashback and have for years without issue.

If i press icons on my top menu bar nothing happens until the freeze passes and then the applications will open up the number of times I've clicked.

I've tried blacklisting nouveau, and installing drivers nvidia-driver-535,525 and 520 and 530 I think. Pretty much tried them all. all same issue.

I've tried to get rid of all sleeping like

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target
sudo systemctl mask suspend.target
sudo systemctl mask hibernate.target
sudo systemctl mask hybrid-sleep.target
```

I even do

```
sudo systemctl disable nvidia-{suspend,resume,hibernate}
```

to ensure its not sleeping.

No matter what I do it will freeze anytime the pc wakes up after it locks. I type in password fine and then it's frozen for 1-2 minutes.

thank you, and any help that's appreciated would be great.

Here are the contents of the `sudo journalctl  --since="-4 minutes"`

```
Dec 02 00:37:13 burri /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3046]: (II) event10 - Logitech Gaming Mouse G402: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
Dec 02 00:37:13 burri audit[1728]: USER_AVC pid=1728 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="P>
                                    exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 02 00:37:13 burri kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(17015433.897:2690): pid=1728 uid=102 auid=42967295 ses=42947295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedes>
                               exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 02 00:37:19 burri gnome-flashback[3239]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Dec 02 00:37:26 burri dbus-daemon[2876]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.58" pid=34975 label="snap>
Dec 02 00:37:27 burri dbus-daemon[2876]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.58" pid=34975 label="snap>
Dec 02 00:37:28 burri dbus-daemon[2876]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.58" pid=34975 label="snap>
Dec 02 00:37:29 burri dbus-daemon[2876]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.58" pid=34975 label="snap>
Dec 02 00:37:30 burri dbus-daemon[2876]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.58" pid=34975 label="snap>
Dec 02 00:37:31 burri dbus-daemon[2876]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.58" pid=34975 label="snap>
Dec 02 00:37:31 burri dbus-daemon[2876]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.58" pid=34975 label="snap>
Dec 02 00:37:32 burri dbus-daemon[2876]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.58" pid=34975 label="snap>
Dec 02 00:37:32 burri dbus-daemon[2876]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.58" pid=34975 label="snap>
Dec 02 00:37:36 burri dbus-daemon[2876]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.58" pid=34975 label="snap>
Dec 02 00:37:38 burri rtkit-daemon[2329]: Supervising 8 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Dec 02 00:37:38 burri rtkit-daemon[2329]: Successfully made thread 62862 of process 2865 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Dec 02 00:37:38 burri rtkit-daemon[2329]: Supervising 9 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Dec 02 00:37:38 burri dbus-daemon[2876]: [session uid=1000 pid=2876] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.874' (uid=1000 pid=62866 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real " label="unc>
Dec 02 00:37:38 burri systemd[2856]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Dec 02 00:37:39 burri dbus-daemon[2876]: [session uid=1000 pid=2876] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Dec 02 00:37:39 burri systemd[2856]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Dec 02 00:37:39 burri systemd[2856]: Started VTE child process 62900 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 62869.
Dec 02 00:37:41 burri dbus-daemon[2876]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.58" pid=34975 label="snap>
Dec 02 00:37:43 burri dbus-daemon[2876]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.58" pid=34975 label="snap>
Dec 02 00:37:44 burri sudo[62942]:      bob : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/bob ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl '--since=-4 minutes'
Dec 02 00:37:44 burri sudo[62942]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1000)
```

pid 34975 is firefox.

Comment: You seem to be on the dangerous path to a Well-known Error: Applying a "solution" before diagnosing the problem. This almost never works. Use the terminal command `sudo journalctl  --since="-4 minutes"` will show you what your system was doing. Read each line carefully. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Oh I have looked at logs very thoroughly and there's nothing of merit in there. It's crazy how there's nothing in any log.

Comment: @waltinator I added the content of those logs. Not sure if you see anything that maybe I'm missing. Thank you